# Pulling a 33,000-record recordset took LESS execution time than using Count() in the SQL. How is that possible?

Tags: sql, count, recordset

Thanks in advance for putting up with me.

Pulling a 33,000-record recordset from the database took LESS execution time than using Count() in the SQL and just grabbing 20 rows.

How is that possible?

A bit more detail:

Before, we were grabbing the entire recordset yet only displaying 20 rows of it on a page at a time for pagination.  That was cringeworthy and wasteful, so I redesigned the page to only grab 20 rows at a time and to simply use an index variable to grab the next page, and so on.

All well and good, but that lacked a record count, which our people needed.

So after the record query, I added (what I thought would be) a quick query just on the index of the table using the Count(index) function in Structured Query Language.

A side by side comparison of the original page and my new page indicates my new page takes roughly 10% longer to execute than the original!  I was flabbergasted.  I thought for sure it would be lightning fast, way faster than the original.

Any thoughts on why and what I might do to remedy that?

Is it because the script has to run two queries, regardless of the data retrieved?

**Update:**

Here is the SQL.

(Table names and field names are fictionalized in this post for security, but the structure is the same as the real page).

The main recordset select query contains:

```
SELECT
    top 21 roster_id, roster_pplid, roster_pplemailid, roster_emailid, roster_firstname, 
    roster_lastname, roster_since, roster_pplsubscrid, roster_firstppldone, roster_pmtcurrent, 
    roster_emailverified, roster_active, roster_selfcanceled, roster_deactreason 
FROM roster
WHERE
    roster_siteid = 22
    AND   roster_isdeleted = false
order by roster_id desc
```

The record count query contains:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(roster_id)
FROM
    roster
WHERE
    roster_siteid = 22
    AND   roster_isdeleted = false
```

The first query runs, then the second.  The second always dynamically has the same matching WHERE filter.

Comment: Where is the sql?

Comment: I didn't paste the SQL because it was more of a theoretical question, but I'll try to get a version of it together and get it on here.  And thanks.

Comment: The SQL queries are there now.    :)

Comment: Have you compared the raw sql run times by running them in SSMS?  How is the code written to run the two sql statements now?  There is some application overhead in opening a connection, executing a command, parsing the data result, and closing the connection.  Could this be the difference in old speed vs new?

Comment: The explanation of your test does not match your question title. There may be any number of reasons your page takes longer. You really need to do some timing and analysis and work out why.

Comment: Thanks all.  The pages are equal in every way, the only difference being that in the old page we would just grab the whole darn table and use recordcount.  The new method is shown above.  We just used a timer on the page and ran several tests.

I suppose it could just be because of the two connections, as suggested.  Maybe my new page is actually faster once it gets up into the 300,000 records, who knows.

Comment: The other difference is the "only grab 20 rows at a time" bit right? It's not clear how you're doing that. The posted SQL Query doesn't do it - it's still grabbing everything. I'm saying that _two_ things have changed here. You need to time both queries (in code) before you assume the count is adding all that time. It might also help to indicate that actual type of database server. (SQL Server? Oracle?) `false` is not a piece of SQL I'm familiar with.

Comment: It seems like `row_number` accompanied by a `partition by` might do the trick here... I can't imagine the count should take a long time, unless your index fails to include `roster_isdeleted`.

Comment: Nick.McDermaid :  The SQL shown is selecting the TOP 21 rows, that is how it is grabbing just 20 rows (number 21 is just to populate the index for the "Next" page link).

Comment: I think I know why it is slower, I'm using GetRows to grab the recordset in the new page, was not using that in the old page.  That seems to be the slowdown.  But I have to use it, cannot step beyond the 21st record otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why it is slower, I'm using GetRows to grab the recordset in the new page, was not using that in the old page. That seems to be the slowdown. But I have to use it, cannot step beyond the 21st record otherwise.

Nick.McDermaid : The SQL shown is selecting the TOP 21 rows, that is how it is grabbing just 20 rows (number 21 is just to populate the index for the "Next" page link).

Comment: Sorry I missed that `TOP` bit. So to get rows 21-40 do you use TOP 41? Anyway, so your question title is definitely misleading. Not sure what you do in this case. Probably ask a new question but this time with the two different code samples, linking to this question.